# How to setup a static foreground image in CSS that covers the entire page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In CSS, how do I setup an image like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1y8zkiwcq80p2dc/ygb-t.png?dl=0 as the foreground that remains static and fits to any screen despite the monitor/browser resolution?

The idea is to have other images behind this, and as you scroll only the background images move. Creating an image overlay effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do that, but this is how I would do it.  This will stretch the image to fit the width of any screen, and the height will remain proportional.  The top and bottom, if empty, will be filled in by the `.padding` `div`s:

`

```css
.bg{
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.img {
  width:100vw;
  align-self: center;
  
  height: auto;
}

.padding {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: pink;  //MAKE THIS THE COLOR OF YOUR IMAGE
}

.content {
  height: 300vh;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
    <div class='padding'></div>
    <img class='img' src="https://photos-3.dropbox.com/t/2/AACmD9Oh8XyU7XsuoMbGiFvhR74Kyf2mmCrvJnHqoPIyQA/12/548079133/png/32x32/3/1528948800/0/2/ygb-t.png/EJK827EEGEYgAigC/X_nlbu7xSKtG1OsirOK65Kyxjviska-5QQCExTwpanM%2ChhX24rQp1YsmgIno_q-Sb66Y78jGxhYf_ZswlAPtHwI?dl=0&preserve_transparency=1&size=1600x1200&size_mode=3">  
    <div class='padding'></div>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Kind of messy with the divs and inline styling, but this is a way you could have what you want and instead of having the colors you would set the background of each div to the picture you would want

```html
 <body style="height: 200vh;">
        <div class="1" style="height: 20vh;
    background-color: red;"></div>
        <div class="1" style="height: 20vh;
    background-color: red;"></div>
        <div class="1" style="height: 20vh;
    background-color: red;"></div>
        <div class="1" style="height: 20vh;
    background-color: green;"></div>
        <div class="1" style="height: 20vh;
    background-color: blue;"></div>
        <div class="1" style="height: 20vh;
    background-color: yellow;"></div>
        <div class="1" style="height: 20vh;
    background-color: orange;"></div>
        <div class="1" style="height: 20vh;
    background-color: purple;"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <img class="stay" src="https://photos-3.dropbox.com/t/2/AACmD9Oh8XyU7XsuoMbGiFvhR74Kyf2mmCrvJnHqoPIyQA/12/548079133/png/32x32/3/1528948800/0/2/ygb-t.png/EJK827EEGEYgAigC/X_nlbu7xSKtG1OsirOK65Kyxjviska-5QQCExTwpanM%2ChhX24rQp1YsmgIno_q-Sb66Y78jGxhYf_ZswlAPtHwI?dl=0&preserve_transparency=1&size=1600x1200&size_mode=3" style="vertical-align: middle;
    border-style: none;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;">
        </div>
      </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a partially transparent image (i.e. with only a few non-transparent areas, like in your example, most likely in `png` format) and put it centered into a container that has `position: fixed` and full window size, like this:

```
.container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

The rest of the content (i.e. your moving background images) has to be *outside*  this container.

ADDITION:

To make the image size relative to the window, give it a percentage-based size like this:

```
.container img {
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mKwZVV (using text instead of background images and in lack of a partially transparent placeholder image, just a "normal" image)